# Нужна помощь в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения, парсер

Всем привет.

Проблема такая, делаю не большой парсер все уже готово, осталась только составить правильную регулярку, помогите пожалуйста.

Есть сайт, на странице которого присутствуют вот таких результаты

```
<td><a href='/simplesearch?domainsimple=site.ru&fromadvs=1'>site.ru</a></td>

<td><font color='green'>Свободен</font><div style="margin: 3px 0 3px 0;"><a style='font-size: x-small; color: green;' target='_blank' href='https://www.nic.ru/manager/registration.cgi?ipartner=3140&step=new_srv.select_pack&new_domain=site.ru&Next=1&rst=all' title='site.ru свободен и вы можете его зарегистрировать.'>Занять <img border='0' src='/img/green.gif'></a></div></td>
<td>
    <font style='color: #f5989d;'>Нет IP</font>
</td>
```

Нужна такая регулярка которая бы вытаскивала **site.ru**, но вытаскивала только в том месте где есть надпись **Нет IP**, а  где стоит ip пропускала.

Все, что удалось найти это

```
(?<=<a\ href="/simplesearch\?domainsimple=).*(?=&amp;)
```

Но такая регулярка парсит все результаты, а необходимо только те где надпись, Нет IP.

Comment: Вы не должны пользоваться регулярками для разбора HTML. Особенно если структура меняется. Возьмите честный HTML-парсер.

Comment: А чем вытаскиваете html код? Какой язык, какая библиотека?

Answer (score 2):

**VladD** что за "честный HTML-парсер"?

Структура там особо не меняется, принцип вот такой:

```
site.ru    Нет IP
site1.ru   100.101.102.103
site2.ru   100.101.102.103
site3.ru   Нет IP
site4.ru   100.101.102.103
```

Я сделал проект на ЗенноПостере, типа парсера теперь мне не обходима регулярка, которая бы собрала, только сайты где написанно Нет IP.

Мне смогли подсказать только вот такую:

```
(?<=<a\ href="/simplesearch\?domainsimple=).*(?=&amp;)
```

Но она парсит, все сайты подряд.

Comment: Зависит от языка, конечно. На C# можно взять, например, [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). На PHP [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

И т. д.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но для меня к сожалению это темный лес.

Comment: Разбирая HTML регекспами вы будете постоянно ломать себе ноги о свои же собственные костыли. Причём этих костылей будет на порядки больше, чем ног :) Так что имеет смысл один раз разобраться, и пользоваться надёжными инструментами.

Comment: Один из самых эпичных ответов SO о регексах и HTML
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Шикарно :)

>Every time you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers pwn your webapp